# How to revoke svn checkout

Tags: linux, svn

I have checkout from svn repository to wrong folder with depth=empty option. I cannot delete that folder, but I dont want to see the svn icons on the folders inside that folder. How can I revoke that checkout. Is there a way to handle this.

Thanks for advance!

Comment: What does "revoke checkout" mean exactly? Do you want to remove versioned files and leave unversioned ones?

Comment: I have cheack out using depth=empty option, so inside the folder there is no versioned folder or file. However I am using rabbitSVN on linux and it shows question mark on all folders and files. This is disturbing me.

Comment: The only thing that makes a directory a Subversion working copy is the `.svn` directory. Remove it and it'll no longer be one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete `.svn` folder inside "wrong folder"

Comment: I have deleted that folder, however the problem is remaining.

Comment: If the actual problem is that RabbitVCS is caching working copy status... I don't know that program but screenshots show a "reload" icon in main toolbar...